# Why is the sort feature always grayed out in the Podcasts app on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, podcasts.app

No matter what screen I'm on, it's always the same.... unable to sort.  Why even include the feature at all?  Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say it's a Catalina bug.  I have 10.15 and have dozens of different podcasts downloaded.

I couldn't get those menu items to be enabled.  I tried all different kinds of variations of selecting/not selecting podcasts and it never worked.

Hopefully, this will be fixed in a future patch or someone will add an answer telling us what we're doing wrong.